# How can I keep strings together when manipulating a python list?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create all unique combinations of a set of strings which are contained in a list.  The issue is that instead of getting the unique combinations of words within the strings I'm getting all individual letter combinations.  What do I have to change in this code to keep the words together?

```
from itertools import combinations

mylist = ['green bird','black dog','tan cat']
tlist = list(
    map(lambda x: list(combinations(x, 2)), mylist)
)

tlist[0:3]
```

gives

```
    [[('g', 'r'),
  ('g', 'e'),
  ('g', 'e'),
  ('g', 'n'),
  ('g', ' '),
  ('g', 'b'),
  ('g', 'i'),
  ('g', 'r'),
  ('g', 'd'),
...
```

but I want

```
[[('green bird', 'black dog'), ('green bird', 'tan cat'), ('black dog', 'tan cat')]]
```

Comment: `tlist = list(combinations(mylist, 2))`

Comment: You want combinations of the list elements; no `map` needed. `combinations(mylist, 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are making it more complicated than it needs to be.  `combinations` [will already generate](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) the combinations for you given an `iterable` and an intended sequence length `r`.

The output is a `generator` so to get your list you just need to call `list()` on it once.

```py
from itertools import combinations

tlist = list(combinations(mylist, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it:

```
from itertools import combinations

mylist = ['green bird','black dog','tan cat']
result = list(combinations(mylist, 2))
print(result)
```

output:

```
[('green bird', 'black dog'), ('green bird', 'tan cat'), ('black dog', 'tan cat')]
```